# Let $G'=b\Bbb Z[G]/(\Bbb Z[G]\cap b\Bbb Z[G]).$ Prove $G'$ is a group of order $|G|$. Find condition to have $G'\cong G$ as groups and justify answer

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $g$ and $\mathbb{Z}[G] \subset \mathbb{Q}[G]$ be the group algebras of $G$ with integer and rational coefficients, respectively. let $$b\mathbb{Z}[G] = \{ba\in\mathbb{Q}[G]|a \in \mathbb{Z}[G]\}$$
for $b = g^{-1}\sum_{h \in G}h \in \mathbb{Q}[G]$, and define a group
$$G' = b\mathbb{Z}[G]/(\mathbb{Z}[G] \cap b\mathbb{Z}[G])$$

Prove that $G'$ is a group of order $g$. Find a necessary and sufficient condition to have $G' \cong G$ as groups and justify your answer

I know that $G'$ is a group under addition whereas $G$ is a group under 'multiplication'. But beside that I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Here $e$ is a bad choice of symbol: it denotes the identity of a group, typically, in group theory.  Please change it.

Comment: What is $j$? ${}$

Comment: thanks for the edits. I've fixed the typos

Comment: What's stopping $G$ from being $(\Bbb Z_p, +_p)$?  That's a group under addition.

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: @Shaun: pretty sure this is problem 1 of the Fall 2008 UCLA algebra qualifying exam: https://ww3.math.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/algebra-08F.pdf

Comment: Thank you, @AlexWertheim :)

Comment: Hint: given $b$, what does $bh$ look like for any $h\in H$? Then what does $ba$ look like for any $a\in \mathbb{Z}[G]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem looks harder than it is - the solution is very pleasant, assuming I haven't made any mistakes. :)

Here is one approach, given in a series of hints for you to flesh out. I claim that $G'$ is cyclic of order $g$. Indeed, you can prove this as follows:

1. First, show that $[0], [b], [2b], \ldots, [(g-1)b]$ are all distinct classes in $G'$. Note that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $[nb]$ is equivalent to one of these classes.
2. Then, show that for any $x = \sum_{k \in G} a_{k}k \in \mathbb{Z}[G]$, we have $bx = (\sum_{k \in G} a_{k})b$. Thus, every element of $G'$ is equivalent to one of the classes listed in step 1. (Hint: what does right multiplying $b$ by an element of $G$ do?)
3. We conclude that it is necessary and sufficient for $G$ to be cyclic of order $g$ in order for $G$ and $G'$ to be isomorphic as groups.